# error installing neural_renderer_pytorch in google colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

error installing neural_renderer_pytorch in google colab

can someone help me with this, i try to install `neural_renderer_pytorch`
But I can't make it, I don't know what's wrong

GPU 0: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB (UUID: GPU-415e05e7-6236-d11b-c02d-65f7fec9509f)

```
!pip install neural_renderer_pytorch 




Collecting neural_renderer_pytorch
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/28/dd59b5098e60e75948ae414ee65700597217199591dffa22797f47914702/neural_renderer_pytorch-1.1.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: torch in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from neural_renderer_pytorch) (1.7.0 + cu101)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from neural_renderer_pytorch) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-image in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from neural_renderer_pytorch) (0.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: dataclasses in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from torch-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from torch-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from torch-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib! = 3.0.0,> = 2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-image-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy> = 0.19.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-image-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow> = 4.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-image-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (7.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: imageio> = 2.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-image-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (2.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx> = 2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-image-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: PyWavelets> = 0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-image-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver> = 1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib! = 3.0.0,> = 2.0.0-> scikit-image-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (1.3 .1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing! = 2.0.4,! = 2.1.2,! = 2.1.6,> = 2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib! = 3.0. 0,> = 2.0.0-> scikit-image-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler> = 0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib! = 3.0.0,> = 2.0.0-> scikit-image-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (0.10.0 )
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil> = 2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib! = 3.0.0,> = 2.0.0-> scikit-image-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (2.8 .1)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator> = 4.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from networkx> = 2.0-> scikit-image-> neural_renderer_pytorch) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from cycler> = 0.10-> matplotlib! = 3.0.0,> = 2.0.0-> scikit-image-> neural_renderer_pytorch) ( 1.15.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: neural-renderer-pytorch
  Building wheel for neural-renderer-pytorch (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for neural-renderer-pytorch
  Running setup.py clean for neural-renderer-pytorch
Failed to build neural-renderer-pytorch
Installing collected packages: neural-renderer-pytorch
    Running setup.py install for neural-renderer-pytorch ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: / usr / bin / python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv [0] = '"'" '/tmp/pip-install-2e3k5ftk/neural-renderer-pytorch/setup.py' "'"'; __file __ = '"'" '/ tmp / pip-install-2e3k5ftk / neural-renderer-pytorch / setup.py' "'"'; f = getattr (tokenize, '"'" 'open' "'"', open ) (__ file __); code = f.read (). replace ('"'" '\ r \ n' "'"', '"'" '\ n' "'"'); f.close (); exec (compile (code, __file__, '"'" 'exec' "'"')) 'install --record /tmp/pip-record-bh0wf0zd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed - -compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `!pip install http://jasonyzhang.com/phosa_data/neural_renderer_pytorch-1.1.3-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl` try this:

Answer (score 0):

Try changing runtime type to gpu instead of none